# Iterate through upper triangular matrix in Python

Tags: python

I am using Python and I have a XxY matrix where X=Y and I want to iterate over the upper triangular matrix in a specific way such that it starts with [image] and proceeds with [image] and [image] and so on and so forth until the last row and column. Therefore, I tried to create a double loop which loops over the columns one by one and within that loop I created another loop which loops over the rows always adding one row. However, I got stuck in defining how to add the next row for every column in the second loop. Here is what I got so far (for simplicity I just created an array of zeros):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# number of columns
X = 10
# number or rows
Y = X

U = np.zeros((Y,X))

for j in range(X):
    for z in range():
```

My initial idea was to create an array of Yx1 with `y = np.asarray(list(range(0,Y)))`and use it for the second loop but I don't understand how to implement it. Can somebody please help me? Is there maybe a simpler way to define such an iteration?

Comment: `for z in range(j, X+1): ...` (diagonal elements included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Numpy, you can get the indices for the upper triangular matrix with [`triu_indices_from`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices_from.html) and index into the array with that:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(16).reshape([4, 4])
print(a)
#[[ 0  1  2  3]
# [ 4  5  6  7]
# [ 8  9 10 11]
# [12 13 14 15]]

indices = np.triu_indices_from(a)

upper = a[indices]
print(upper)
# [ 0  1  2  3  5  6  7 10 11 15]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Wouldn't that overwrite the values in the matrix? I just took zeros here for simplicity's sake but in reality I have a matrix with specific values.

Comment: Not sure I understand @Phil, nothing in the above code alters `a`. Indices is a new array of indices, which you use to index in `a`.  `upper` is a new array based on that indexing. `a` remains the same throughout.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I misunderstood your code as I thought a is my original matrix U and not a new one!

Comment: If I want to keep the the size of the matrix variable, how would I write that such that it keeps the running integers? I tried with `np.array` and `np.arange`, but I couldn't find it out.